# Does the term NoSQL fit inside a DBMS?

Tags: database, rdbms, nosql

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Types_of_DBMS), a Database Management System consists of four main types:

```
1 Hierarchical DBMS

2 Network DBMS

3 Relational DBMS

4 Object-oriented DBMS
```

I was wondering whether the term NoSQL is also a type of DBMS. If it does not, where does it belong to? Or can't it be seen as a DBMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "SQL" here essentially means "Relational". So [NoSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) as "no SQL" = non-Relational and as "not only SQL" = anything but emphasizing also having some Relational capabilities.

So "NoSQL" would be a category/kind of DBMS, and we would a expect "NoSQL DBMS" to be used to describe a DBMS with various combinations from your list (and others). Although the details would depend on the speaker's explanation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So NoSQL is essentially like a number 5 in that list.

Comment: As my answer says, NoSQL includes all non-3 types and more, eg graph, because SQL is meant to be 3. It's not a matter of adding to that list. Plus, RDBMSs can deal with all those kinds of subject matter, it's just not specialized to them.